# updating android activity when a user taps a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I use this code, inside a notification, so when the user taps the notification the MainActivity starts:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
```

If the user exits the app with the back button and taps a notification then main activity starts but if the user exit the app with the home button a new MainActivity starts over the first one. How can I detect if the MainActivity is loaded?

Thkx

Answer (score 0):

You should add flags to your Intent to specify this behavior. Something like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` may be what you're looking for. This will finish any Activities on top of MainActivity (if any) and bring any existing instance to the foreground. If no instance is available, one will be created. Depending on your `launchMode`, you'll either get a callback to `onNewIntent()` (receiving the new Intent you provided) or the activity will be recreated with the new Intent.

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent, 0);
```